# Why does a difference of opinion affect votes so much?

Tags: discussion, voting

Sometimes you see questions that attract some negative input.

For example, [this game identification question about Fallout 3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/202612/from-which-game-is-this-image-of-picking-a-lock-on-a-broken-door) received some heat, some heated discussions arose and next thing we know, a Game ID question has an answer with 51 votes!

I have seen this on some other sites, where some users feel the question is not worthy of the site, or the answers are incorrect, or whatever reason they seem to put forward, but after a bit of struggle, the original question and some of the answers get a huge boost in votes.

What is the correlation between these events?

Comment: If it gets bumped onto the 'hot network question' list, it'll attract a lot of views/discussion